# Headless browser testing

Tags: automated-testing, c#, headless

I have a question around headless browser testing which I am looking to utilise in my automation framework, which is written in c#. Headless browser testing is not an area I'm familiar with but I'm looking to leverage it's capabilities as I'm looking at quickly creating some orders on a test website, but I'm not actually concerned with how the UI looks and behaves; I just want to ensure the order lands in the db correctly.

As a result of the above I have a couple of questions:

1) When writing a framework in c# are there any recommended tools for this that I can look into?

2) Are there any good tutorials/code examples out there that I can utilise?

Comment: For creating lots of orders fast you can skip the client side rendering. Just simulate the http traffic like for instance JMeter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*When writing a framework in c# are there any recommended tools for this that I can look into?* Its totally depends on you aim and requirement as per current trend Selenium is most popular now days. You can refer the [official](https://www.seleniumhq.org/) site.
You can configure the test to be execute in headless mode (even in chrome and Firefox) easily.

*I'm not actually concerned with how the UI looks and behaves;* 
There is no UI in headless mode as it executes the browser as background process.
You can analyze the test result based on logs and screenshots (it captures the same snap of webpage as you see while execute the test in non headless mode)

*Are there any good tutorials/code examples out there that I can utilize?* There is large selenium support community even you can easily find the tutorial from beginner to expert just type the same in google.